# Volume issue - AVAudioPlayer mixed with AudioServices System Sound

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, audio, avaudioplayer

I've big problem with handling sounds in my game. I'm using AVAudioPlayer for BG music and AudioServices system sound for short sound FX. There's issue with volume.

Changing volume down in game affects background music and SFX volume. If it's muted, all is muted. But volume up affects correctly only background music but SFX goes to it's maximum regarding of main Sound Effects Volume setting. If sound effects volume is set to 0, I got no SFX but music is playing correctly. Hope it's clear.

How can I adjust volume of both of them in game??

Please help me becuase deadline is coming :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, I wrote short blog post about it: https://coderwall.com/p/jslwrg

Comment: I have same problem in my game, I did as you mentioned above but I do not know what should I do next. still after adding this library problem exist. Should I replace some lines in my code also? or just adding such this library would solve the problem?